# calling function and ignoring callback parameter

Tags: javascript, callback

I want to call this:

```
function fwc(a, b, callback) {

dosomestuff(a,b);
callback();
}
```

with this:

```
fwc (a,b);
```

Sometimes i need the callback and sometimes I don't. Can this cause trouble when I call the function and completely ignore the callback?

Answer (score 5):

If you can't change the `fwc` function, you can call it like this :

```
fwc(a, b, function(){});
```

This way there won't be an error when `fwc` tries to call the third argument.

If you can change it, change it to

```
function fwc(a, b, callback) {
    dosomestuff(a,b);
    if (callback) callback();
}
```

Comment: I think the second approach is preferable over the first. Hopefully the OP can change the implementation of fwc

Answer (score 4):

You should check the type of your callback like this:

```
function fwc(a, b, callback) {
 dosomestuff(a,b);
 if( typeof( callback ) == "function" ){
  callback();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operator to do a simple check to see if the function exists.

```
function fwc(a, b, callback) {
    dosomestuff(a,b);
   (callback) ? callback():"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or like this:

```
function fwc(a, b, callback) {
    dosomestuff(a,b);
    callback && callback();
}
```

You can also check for `callback` type to make sure it's a function. If so check Travis's general answer.